# Flutter create results in error Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org

Tags: flutter

When I try to create a new flutter project in the command line using flutter create I get the error:
**Got TLS error trying to find package cupertino_icons at https://pub.dartlang.org**

Creating a flutter project in Android Studio gets stuck as well without any error messages.

I'm on Windows 10 and I have the flutter SDK on the C drive and I also have full admin rights on the machine. This is brand new installation of Flutter on a new machine.

I tried running both Android Studio and the command line as an administrator and that didn't help.

Here's the output from flutter doctor -v:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.657], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.12.13+hotfix.8 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision 0b8abb4724 (2 weeks ago), 2020-02-11 11:44:36 -0800
    • Engine revision e1e6ced81d
    • Dart version 2.7.0


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.6)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 43.0.2
    • Dart plugin version 192.7761
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b04)

[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Here's some of the output of flutter create app -v:

```
[  +10 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[ +228 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[   +1 ms] 0b8abb4724aa590dd0f429683339b1e045a1594d
[        ] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[ +213 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[        ] v1.12.13+hotfix.8-0-g0b8abb472
[   +5 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[ +211 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +1 ms] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[ +211 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +1 ms] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[ +240 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter\] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[ +233 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +69 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +25 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +8 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +3 ms] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +26 ms] Creating project mytestapp... androidx: true
[  +24 ms]   mytestapp\.gitignore (created)
[  +10 ms]   mytestapp\.idea\libraries\Dart_SDK.xml (created)
[   +6 ms]   mytestapp\.idea\libraries\Flutter_for_Android.xml (created)
[   +2 ms]   mytestapp\.idea\libraries\KotlinJavaRuntime.xml (created)
[   +4 ms]   mytestapp\.idea\modules.xml (created)
[   +3 ms]   mytestapp\.idea\runConfigurations\main_dart.xml (created)
[   +3 ms]   mytestapp\.idea\workspace.xml (created)
[   +3 ms]   mytestapp\.metadata (created)
[   +2 ms]   mytestapp\android\app\build.gradle (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\android\app\src\main\kotlin\com\example\mytestapp\MainActivity.kt (created)
[  +25 ms]   mytestapp\android\build.gradle (created)
[   +9 ms]   mytestapp\android\mytestapp_android.iml (created)
[   +1 ms]   mytestapp\android\.gitignore (created)
[   +3 ms]   mytestapp\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml (created)
[   +1 ms]   mytestapp\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml (created)
[   +2 ms]   mytestapp\android\app\src\main\res\drawable\launch_background.xml (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-hdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
[   +4 ms]   mytestapp\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-mdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xhdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
[   +4 ms]   mytestapp\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxhdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\android\app\src\main\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi\ic_launcher.png (created)
[   +4 ms]   mytestapp\android\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml (created)
[   +4 ms]   mytestapp\android\app\src\profile\AndroidManifest.xml (created)
[   +4 ms]   mytestapp\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\android\gradle.properties (created)
[   +2 ms]   mytestapp\android\settings.gradle (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\AppDelegate.swift (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Runner-Bridging-Header.h (created)
[   +4 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\project.pbxproj (created)
[   +8 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\xcshareddata\xcschemes\Runner.xcscheme (created)
[   +6 ms]   mytestapp\ios\.gitignore (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Flutter\AppFrameworkInfo.plist (created)
[   +6 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Flutter\Debug.xcconfig (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Flutter\Release.xcconfig (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Contents.json (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-1024x1024@1x.png (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@1x.png (created)
[   +4 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@2x.png (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-20x20@3x.png (created)
[   +4 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@1x.png (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@2x.png (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-29x29@3x.png (created)
[   +7 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@1x.png (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@2x.png (created)
[   +6 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-40x40@3x.png (created)
[   +4 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-60x60@2x.png (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-60x60@3x.png (created)
[   +6 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-76x76@1x.png (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-76x76@2x.png (created)
[   +4 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\AppIcon.appiconset\Icon-App-83.5x83.5@2x.png (created)
[   +6 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\Contents.json (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\LaunchImage.png (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\LaunchImage@2x.png (created)
[   +6 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\LaunchImage@3x.png (created)
[   +6 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Assets.xcassets\LaunchImage.imageset\README.md (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Base.lproj\LaunchScreen.storyboard (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Base.lproj\Main.storyboard (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner\Info.plist (created)
[   +2 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\project.xcworkspace\contents.xcworkspacedata (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\ios\Runner.xcodeproj\xcshareddata\xcschemes\Runner.xcscheme (existing - skipped)
[        ]   mytestapp\ios\Runner.xcworkspace\contents.xcworkspacedata (created)
[   +4 ms]   mytestapp\lib\main.dart (created)
[   +4 ms]   mytestapp\mytestapp.iml (created)
[   +2 ms]   mytestapp\pubspec.yaml (created)
[   +3 ms]   mytestapp\README.md (created)
[   +5 ms]   mytestapp\test\widget_test.dart (created)
[  +33 ms] Running "flutter pub get" in mytestapp...
[   +3 ms] Using C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache for the pub cache.
[   +2 ms] executing: [c:\flutter_projects\mytestapp\] C:\src\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat --verbose get
--no-precompile
[ +449 ms] FINE: Pub 2.7.0
[   +2 ms] IO  : Spawning "cmd /c ver" in c:\flutter_projects\mytestapp\.
[  +51 ms] IO  : Finished ver. Exit code 0.
[   +1 ms]     | stdout:
[        ]     | |
[        ]     | | Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.657]
[        ]     | Nothing output on stderr.
[  +34 ms] MSG : Resolving dependencies...
[   +7 ms] SLVR: fact: mytestapp is 1.0.0+1
[   +2 ms] SLVR: derived: mytestapp
[  +17 ms] SLVR: fact: mytestapp depends on flutter any from sdk
[   +6 ms] SLVR: fact: mytestapp depends on cupertino_icons ^0.1.2
[   +1 ms] SLVR: fact: mytestapp depends on flutter_test any from sdk
[   +1 ms] SLVR:   selecting mytestapp
[   +2 ms] SLVR:   derived: flutter_test any from sdk
[   +4 ms] SLVR:   derived: cupertino_icons ^0.1.2
[        ] SLVR:   derived: flutter any from sdk
[   +2 ms] IO  : Get versions from https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/cupertino_icons.
[  +13 ms] IO  : HTTP GET https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/cupertino_icons
[        ]     | Accept: application/vnd.pub.v2+json
[   +6 ms]     | X-Pub-OS: windows
[        ]     | X-Pub-Command: get
[   +3 ms]     | X-Pub-Session-ID: 12B32BE8-FB1F-481E-B6B4-8A8C643EEF43
[   +1 ms]     | X-Pub-Environment: flutter_cli:create
[   +1 ms]     | X-Pub-Reason: direct
[   +2 ms]     | user-agent: Dart pub 2.7.0
[ +475 ms] IO  : HTTP error:
[   +2 ms]     | HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
[        ]     |        CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:354))
[        ]     |
[   +1 ms]     | dart:_http                                         _HttpClient.openUrl
[        ]     | package:http/src/io_client.dart 33:36              IOClient.send
[        ]     | package:pub/src/http.dart 68:39                    _PubHttpClient.send
[        ]     | package:http_retry/http_retry.dart 97:33           RetryClient.send
[        ]     | package:pub/src/http.dart 194:43                   _ThrowingClient.send
[        ]     | package:http_throttle/http_throttle.dart 33:31     ThrottleClient.send
[   +2 ms]     | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
[        ]     | dart:async                                         _asyncThenWrapperHelper
[   +2 ms]     | package:http_throttle/http_throttle.dart           ThrottleClient.send
[        ]     | package:http/src/base_client.dart 169:38           BaseClient._sendUnstreamed
[        ]     | package:http/src/base_client.dart 32:7             BaseClient.get
[        ]     | package:http/src/base_client.dart 117:12           BaseClient.read
[        ]     | package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 160:31          BoundHostedSource.doGetVersions
[        ]     | package:pub/src/source.dart 167:12                 BoundSource.getVersions
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver/package_lister.dart 76:44   PackageLister._versions.<fn>.<fn>
[   +1 ms]     | dart:async                                         runZoned
[        ]     | package:pub/src/http.dart 272:10                   withDependencyType
[   +2 ms]     | package:pub/src/solver/package_lister.dart 75:33   PackageLister._versions.<fn>
[        ]     | dart:async                                         new Future.sync
[   +4 ms]     | package:async/src/async_memoizer.dart 43:42        AsyncMemoizer.runOnce
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver/package_lister.dart 74:58   PackageLister._versions
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver/package_lister.dart 111:21  PackageLister.countVersions
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 354:44  VersionSolver._choosePackageVersion.<fn>
[        ]     | package:pub/src/utils.dart 301:39                  minByAsync
[   +2 ms]     | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
[   +3 ms]     | dart:async                                         _asyncThenWrapperHelper
[        ]     | package:pub/src/utils.dart                         minByAsync
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 350:25  VersionSolver._choosePackageVersion
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 97:22   VersionSolver.solve
[        ]     | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
[        ]     | dart:async                                         _asyncThenWrapperHelper
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart         VersionSolver.solve
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver.dart 35:10                  resolveVersions.<fn>
[   +2 ms]     | package:pub/src/log.dart 378:18                    progress
[   +3 ms]     | package:pub/src/solver.dart 32:10                  resolveVersions
[        ]     | package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 217:24             Entrypoint.acquireDependencies
[        ]     | package:pub/src/command/get.dart 41:23             GetCommand.run
[        ]     | package:args/command_runner.dart 197:27            CommandRunner.runCommand
[        ]     | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 171:39         PubCommandRunner.runCommand.<fn>
[        ]     | dart:async                                         new Future.sync
[        ]     | package:pub/src/utils.dart 109:12                  captureErrors.<fn>
[        ]     | package:stack_trace                                Chain.capture
[   +2 ms]     | package:pub/src/utils.dart 122:11                  captureErrors
[   +3 ms]     | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 171:13         PubCommandRunner.runCommand
[ +644 ms] IO  : Retry #1 for GET https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/cupertino_icons...
[   +3 ms] IO  : HTTP GET https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/cupertino_icons
[   +2 ms]     | Accept: application/vnd.pub.v2+json
[        ]     | X-Pub-OS: windows
[        ]     | X-Pub-Command: get
[        ]     | X-Pub-Session-ID: 12B32BE8-FB1F-481E-B6B4-8A8C643EEF43
[        ]     | X-Pub-Environment: flutter_cli:create
[        ]     | X-Pub-Reason: direct
[   +1 ms]     | user-agent: Dart pub 2.7.0
[ +249 ms] IO  : HTTP error:
[   +1 ms]     | HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
[        ]     |        CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:354))
[        ]     |
[        ]     | dart:_http                                         _HttpClient.openUrl
[        ]     | package:http/src/io_client.dart 33:36              IOClient.send
[        ]     | package:pub/src/http.dart 68:39                    _PubHttpClient.send
[        ]     | package:http_retry/http_retry.dart 97:33           RetryClient.send
[        ]     | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
[        ]     | dart:async                                         _asyncThenWrapperHelper
[        ]     | package:http_retry/http_retry.dart                 RetryClient.send
[        ]     | package:pub/src/http.dart 194:43                   _ThrowingClient.send
[   +2 ms]     | package:http_throttle/http_throttle.dart 33:31     ThrottleClient.send
[        ]     | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
[   +3 ms]     | dart:async                                         _asyncThenWrapperHelper
[        ]     | package:http_throttle/http_throttle.dart           ThrottleClient.send
[        ]     | package:http/src/base_client.dart 169:38           BaseClient._sendUnstreamed
[        ]     | package:http/src/base_client.dart 32:7             BaseClient.get
[        ]     | package:http/src/base_client.dart 117:12           BaseClient.read
[        ]     | package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 160:31          BoundHostedSource.doGetVersions
[        ]     | package:pub/src/source.dart 167:12                 BoundSource.getVersions
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver/package_lister.dart 76:44   PackageLister._versions.<fn>.<fn>
[        ]     | dart:async                                         runZoned
[   +1 ms]     | package:pub/src/http.dart 272:10                   withDependencyType
[   +2 ms]     | package:pub/src/solver/package_lister.dart 75:33   PackageLister._versions.<fn>
[        ]     | dart:async                                         new Future.sync
[        ]     | package:async/src/async_memoizer.dart 43:42        AsyncMemoizer.runOnce
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver/package_lister.dart 74:58   PackageLister._versions
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver/package_lister.dart 111:21  PackageLister.countVersions
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 354:44  VersionSolver._choosePackageVersion.<fn>
[        ]     | package:pub/src/utils.dart 301:39                  minByAsync
[        ]     | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
[        ]     | dart:async                                         _asyncThenWrapperHelper
[        ]     | package:pub/src/utils.dart                         minByAsync
[   +3 ms]     | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 350:25  VersionSolver._choosePackageVersion
[   +2 ms]     | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 97:22   VersionSolver.solve
[        ]     | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
[        ]     | dart:async                                         _asyncThenWrapperHelper
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart         VersionSolver.solve
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver.dart 35:10                  resolveVersions.<fn>
[        ]     | package:pub/src/log.dart 378:18                    progress
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver.dart 32:10                  resolveVersions
[        ]     | package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 217:24             Entrypoint.acquireDependencies
[        ]     | package:pub/src/command/get.dart 41:23             GetCommand.run
[        ]     | package:args/command_runner.dart 197:27            CommandRunner.runCommand
[        ]     | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 171:39         PubCommandRunner.runCommand.<fn>
[        ]     | dart:async                                         new Future.sync
[        ]     | package:pub/src/utils.dart 109:12                  captureErrors.<fn>
[   +2 ms]     | package:stack_trace                                Chain.capture
[        ]     | package:pub/src/utils.dart 122:11                  captureErrors
[   +2 ms]     | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 171:13         PubCommandRunner.runCommand
[ +815 ms] IO  : Retry #2 for GET https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/cupertino_icons...
[   +6 ms] IO  : HTTP GET https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/cupertino_icons
[   +4 ms]     | Accept: application/vnd.pub.v2+json
[   +6 ms]     | X-Pub-OS: windows
[   +4 ms]     | X-Pub-Command: get
[   +6 ms]     | X-Pub-Session-ID: 12B32BE8-FB1F-481E-B6B4-8A8C643EEF43
[   +3 ms]     | X-Pub-Environment: flutter_cli:create
[   +1 ms]     | X-Pub-Reason: direct
[   +1 ms]     | user-agent: Dart pub 2.7.0
[ +226 ms] IO  : HTTP error:
[   +1 ms]     | HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
[        ]     |        CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:354))
[        ]     |
[        ]     | dart:_http                                         _HttpClient.openUrl
[        ]     | package:http/src/io_client.dart 33:36              IOClient.send
[        ]     | package:pub/src/http.dart 68:39                    _PubHttpClient.send
[        ]     | package:http_retry/http_retry.dart 97:33           RetryClient.send
[        ]     | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
[        ]     | dart:async                                         _asyncThenWrapperHelper
[        ]     | package:http_retry/http_retry.dart                 RetryClient.send
[        ]     | package:pub/src/http.dart 194:43                   _ThrowingClient.send
[        ]     | package:http_throttle/http_throttle.dart 33:31     ThrottleClient.send
[        ]     | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
[        ]     | dart:async                                         _asyncThenWrapperHelper
[        ]     | package:http_throttle/http_throttle.dart           ThrottleClient.send
[   +2 ms]     | package:http/src/base_client.dart 169:38           BaseClient._sendUnstreamed
[        ]     | package:http/src/base_client.dart 32:7             BaseClient.get
[   +1 ms]     | package:http/src/base_client.dart 117:12           BaseClient.read
[        ]     | package:pub/src/source/hosted.dart 160:31          BoundHostedSource.doGetVersions
[        ]     | package:pub/src/source.dart 167:12                 BoundSource.getVersions
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver/package_lister.dart 76:44   PackageLister._versions.<fn>.<fn>
[        ]     | dart:async                                         runZoned
[        ]     | package:pub/src/http.dart 272:10                   withDependencyType
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver/package_lister.dart 75:33   PackageLister._versions.<fn>
[        ]     | dart:async                                         new Future.sync
[        ]     | package:async/src/async_memoizer.dart 43:42        AsyncMemoizer.runOnce
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver/package_lister.dart 74:58   PackageLister._versions
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver/package_lister.dart 111:21  PackageLister.countVersions
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 354:44  VersionSolver._choosePackageVersion.<fn>
[        ]     | package:pub/src/utils.dart 301:39                  minByAsync
[   +2 ms]     | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
[        ]     | dart:async                                         _asyncThenWrapperHelper
[   +1 ms]     | package:pub/src/utils.dart                         minByAsync
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 350:25  VersionSolver._choosePackageVersion
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart 97:22   VersionSolver.solve
[        ]     | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
[        ]     | dart:async                                         _asyncThenWrapperHelper
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver/version_solver.dart         VersionSolver.solve
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver.dart 35:10                  resolveVersions.<fn>
[        ]     | package:pub/src/log.dart 378:18                    progress
[        ]     | package:pub/src/solver.dart 32:10                  resolveVersions
[        ]     | package:pub/src/entrypoint.dart 217:24             Entrypoint.acquireDependencies
[        ]     | package:pub/src/command/get.dart 41:23             GetCommand.run
[        ]     | package:args/command_runner.dart 197:27            CommandRunner.runCommand
[        ]     | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 171:39         PubCommandRunner.runCommand.<fn>
[        ]     | dart:async                                         new Future.sync
[   +2 ms]     | package:pub/src/utils.dart 109:12                  captureErrors.<fn>
[        ]     | package:stack_trace                                Chain.capture
[   +1 ms]     | package:pub/src/utils.dart 122:11                  captureErrors
[        ]     | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 171:13         PubCommandRunner.runCommand
[+1277 ms] IO  : Retry #3 for GET https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/cupertino_icons...
[   +4 ms] IO  : HTTP GET https://pub.dartlang.org/api/packages/cupertino_icons
[        ]     | Accept: application/vnd.pub.v2+json
[        ]     | X-Pub-OS: windows
[        ]     | X-Pub-Command: get
[        ]     | X-Pub-Session-ID: 12B32BE8-FB1F-481E-B6B4-8A8C643EEF43
[        ]     | X-Pub-Environment: flutter_cli:create
[        ]     | X-Pub-Reason: direct
[        ]     | user-agent: Dart pub 2.7.0
[ +260 ms] IO  : HTTP error:
[   +1 ms]     | HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
[        ]     |        CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:354))
[        ]     |
[        ]     | dart:_http                                         _HttpClient.openUrl
[        ]     | package:http/src/io_client.dart 33:36              IOClient.send
[        ]     | package:pub/src/http.dart 68:39                    _PubHttpClient.send
[        ]     | package:http_retry/http_retry.dart 97:33           RetryClient.send
[        ]     | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
[        ]     | dart:async                                         _asyncThenWrapperHelper
[        ]     | package:http_retry/http_retry.dart                 RetryClient.send
[        ]     | package:pub/src/http.dart 194:43                   _ThrowingClient.send
[        ]     | package:http_throttle/http_throttle.dart 33:31     ThrottleClient.send
[        ]     | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
[        ]     | dart:async
```

Running flutter pub get --verbose gives this error:

```
[ +259 ms] IO  : HTTP error:
[   +2 ms]     | HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error:
[        ]     |        CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:354))
```

It could be because of the corporate firewall or certificate but i'm not sure what needs to be done here. I used to be able to run flutter fine on my older laptop within the same environment. Now I have a new laptop so not sure what has changed.

Appreciate any help on this.
Ali

Comment: It works when I login in safe mode. Looks like it's related to the blue coat unified agent installed in our machines. I'll see how to bypass that somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Symantaic Endpoint Protection was configured to use blue coat agent and the unified agent was also installed. So it seems that they were conflicting with each other. After removing the unified agent, now I no longer get that error.